# Binding Python/C++ template with SWIG

Tags: python, c++, binding, swig

I try to bind a C++ template in Python with SWIG.
I want that my typename T can be a float or a double.
I use SWIG 3.0.8

Here is my C++ template : Personnage.hpp (don't read all of this, only 1 function interest us)

```
#ifndef PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
#define PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED

#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

template <typename T> 
class Personnage
{
    public:

        Personnage();

        ~Personnage();

        void setAge(const int &age);

        void setTaille(const T &taille);

        int getAge() const;

        T getTaille() const;


    protected:
        std::string P_nom;

        int P_age;

        T P_taille;
};

template<typename T>
Personnage<T>::Personnage()
: P_nom("Rigoberto"), P_age(42), P_taille(T(1.10))
{
}

template<typename T>
Personnage<T>::~Personnage(){}

template<typename T>
void Personnage<T>::setAge(const int &age)
{
    P_age = age;
}

template<typename T>
void Personnage<T>::setTaille(const T &taille)
{
    P_taille = taille;
}

template<typename T>
int Personnage<T>::getAge() const
{
    return P_age;
}

template<typename T>
T Personnage<T>::getTaille() const
{
    return P_taille;
}



#endif // PERSONNAGE_H_INCLUDED
```

My Personnage.cpp just contains :
    #include "Personnage.hpp"

And here is my interface file : Personnage.i

```
%module Personnage

%{
#include "Personnage.hpp"
%}




%include "Personnage.hpp"

%module Personnage

%{
#include "Personnage.hpp"
%}

%rename (PersonnageD) Personnage::Personnage();
%rename (PersonnageC) Personnage::Personnage(const Personnage<T> &personnage);


%include "Personnage.hpp"
%include "std_string.i"

//constructeurs simples

%template(PFloat) Personnage<float>;
%template(PDouble) Personnage<double>;

%template(estGrand) estGrand<float, float>;
%template(estGrand) estGrand<float, double>;
%template(estGrand) estGrand<double, float>;
%template(estGrand) estGrand<double, double>;
```

I use these line to use SWIG and compile :

```
swig -c++ -python Personnage.i
g++ -fPIC -c Personnage.cpp
g++ -fPIC -c Personnage_wrap.cxx $(python-config --cflags)
g++ -shared Personnage.o Personnage_wrap.o $(python-config --ldflags) -o _Personnage.so
```

and here is my python file that i use to test this :

```
import Personnage
persSimple = Personnage.PDouble("didier",45,1.59) #Player with a "Taille" in Double
print(persSimple.getTaille())
FpersSimple = Personnage.PFloat("didier",45,1.59) #Player with a "Taille" in Float
print(FpersSimple.getTaille())
```

The first print show "1.59", and it's correct.
The second print show "1.5900000(random numbers)", and it is exactly the reason why I ask some help here : it should just show "1.59".

When I type "FpersSimple" on Python, I get :

```
<Personnage.PFloat; proxy of <Swig Object of type 'Personnage< float > *' at 0x7fd2742b3480> >
```

So my FpersSimple contains definitively a float.

I don't understand where i could messed up.

Thank you for your time !

Thank you for your time and your answers !

Comment: Python only knows double, so the float you return will be converted to double and the additonal digits will just be uninitialized memory, but when you print the value, those are also taken into account.

Comment: Hello @HenriMenke !

That's what I thought, thank you for you answer !

Answer (score 1):

Python only knows double, so the float you return will be converted to double and the additonal digits will just be uninitialized memory, but when you print the value, those are also taken into account.

You don't even need a complicated example with SWIG and Python to reproduce this.  Just initialize a float from a double (literal `1.59` is a double) and print it with double precision.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    double d = 1.59;
    float f = 1.59;
    std::cout << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::digits10)
              << std::fixed
              << d << '\n'
              << f << '\n';
}
```

```
1.590000000000000
1.590000033378601
```